# How to use a JSon array in a JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JSon array which is as follows:

```
[{"country":"FR","id":2,"latitude":-34.27175846153846,"longitude":54.16125384615385,"postcode":"00000","region1":"DOM-TOM","region2":"Terres australes et antarctiques","region3":"Crozet","region4":"","version":null},{"country":"FR","id":3,"latitude":46.203635000000006,"longitude":5.20772,"postcode":"01000","region1":"Rhône-Alpes","region2":"Ain","region3":"Bourg-en-Bresse","region4":"Bourg-en-Bresse","version":null}, ...
```

I am trying to use this array as a source for a JQuery autocomplete. Here is what I attempted:

```
$(function() {
    $("#postcode").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            var firstChars = $("#postcode").attr("value");
            $.getJSON("/kadjoukor/geolocations", {
                postcodeFirstChars : firstChars
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data.postcode);
                response(data.postcode);
            });
        },
        minLength : 3,
    });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="member.geolocation.postcode" value="" id="postcode" placeholder="Code postal" />
```

I want to display the postcode variable from this JSon array. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `$("#postcode").attr("value");` should be `request.term` after that, you need to use `$.map` to turn your array into the array format that is expected by autocomplete. There is(was?) a good example of that in the api documentation at http://jqueryui.com

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: @KevinB, Can you please include a code snippet? I am not sure where to  use the `request.term` in the js code... Also what is the array format expected by autocomplete?

Comment: Thanks. I saw this example (remote-jsonp) but it merely logs the result into another div whereas I want the result to appear in the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transform the the result array to label-value pairs. In your case in can be like

```
source : function(request, response) {
        var firstChars = $("#postcode").attr("value");
        $.getJSON("/kadjoukor/geolocations", {
            postcodeFirstChars : firstChars
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data.postcode);
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.postcode,
                        value: item.postcode
                    };
                }));
        });
    },
```

Comment: Hi Lavrik. Thanks for the code. I am not sure how to get to the postcode variable given the json array. It seems data.postcode does not work in the console.log...

Comment: Somehow the `console.log(data.postcode);` line caused the autocompete not to work. By removing this line it now works. Thanks a lot Lavrik!!

Comment: You are welcome :) And yes, your sample data was in square brackets, means it's an array )